# Is it technically possible to determine the identity of the creator/uploader of an image on Twitter?

Tags: privacy

I'm an artist who would like to share his work on Twitter. Because of the subject matter, I don't want my employer or family to find out. I want to stay totally anonymous.

Is it technically possible for someone to determine my identity simply by looking at the properties of the images I upload to Twitter (e.g. metadata)?

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Poorly researched. Yes, Twitter strips EXIF metadata and a simple google search finds this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774758/is-exif-data-striped-by-ios-and-or-twitter-on-tweets-with-images

Answer (score 1):

No. Like the comment said, Twitter strips metadata for a while now. So unless you provide hints and do nothing worth a subpoena, you'll be safe.